# In what way is conditional quantum probability restrictive, and why?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, probability, density-operator, intuition

This is close to a duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/q/412327/ but with a different emphasis. Unlike the mathoverflow equivalent, here I want to ask for your informed intuition as physicists.

To simplify things, let's consider the Hilbert approach to quantum probability over a finite dimensional vector space $V$ of dimension $n$.

In this context a state $S$ is a positive semi-definite trace 1 matrix, and an observable $X$ is any self-adjoint matrix.

The classical probability situation is where all matrices are diagonal, in which case $S$ is equivalent to a probability space over a set of $n$ points, and $X$ is a random variable assigning each sample in the sample space some real number.

In the quantum probability situation, the equivalent of sampling $X$ is Born's rule, which prescribes a (classical) probability measure on the eigenvalues of $X$: the probability of $\lambda$ is $tr(Proj_{E_{X, \lambda}}S)$ where $E_{X, \lambda}$ is the eigenspace of $\lambda$ for $X$. This sums up to $1$ because
$$S=\sum_{\lambda}Proj_{E_{X,\lambda}}S,$$
and trace is additive. In the commutative case this jibes with intuition of course.

Conditional probability works as follows: let $Y$ be another observable. Assume that using Born's rule you get $\lambda$ for $X$ (you got the eigenvalue $\lambda$ when you sampled via Born's rule). Then the "conditional Born's rule for $Y$ given that you got $\lambda$ for Born's rule for $X$" is a (classical) probability distribution over the eigenvalues of $Y$ given by the probability of $\lambda'$ being $tr(Proj_{E_{X,\lambda}}Proj_{E_{Y,\lambda'}}Proj_{E_{X,\lambda}}S)/tr(Proj_{E_{X,\lambda}}S)$. Again, in the commutative case this jibes with intuition about what conditional probability means.

#### Question

In https://mathoverflow.net/q/412327/ it became evident that it is not true that (without knowledge of what $S$ is) knowing the probability distribution over the eigenvalues of $X$ coming from Born's rule (the $tr(Proj_{E_{X,\lambda}}S)$s), and knowing all the conditional probabilities for $Y$ given measurements of $X$ (all of the $tr(Proj_{E_{X,\lambda}}Proj_{E_{Y,\lambda'}}Proj_{E_{X,\lambda}}S)/tr(Proj_{E_{X,\lambda}}S)$s) does not determine the unconditional probabilities for $Y$ (the $tr(Proj_{E_{Y,\lambda'}}S)$s).

This leads me to the main question: In exactly what ways is quantum probability more restrictive than: "for each measurement $\lambda$ of $X$ you can choose any conditional distribution you want for $Y$"?

As subquestions: Can that restriction be written with no reference to linear algebra? If not, how would you justify $tr(Proj_{E_{X,\lambda}}Proj_{E_{Y,\lambda'}}Proj_{E_{X,\lambda}}S)/tr(Proj_{E_{X,\lambda}}S)$ as the conditional distribution for getting $\lambda'$ for $Y$ given that you got $\lambda$ for $X$? What is the intuition here (hopefully other than "shut up and compute" because it jibes with experiments)?

Comment: Isabell Guerra Bobo has written an entire [thesis](https://eprints.ucm.es/id/eprint/10636/1/T31869.pdf) on that subject. I browsed through it a few years ago. Don't remember enough to answer your question but I believe this is what you may want to read.

Comment: @KurtG. The first sentence of the Abstract of this thesis is: "In this dissertation we argue against the possibility of defining a notion of conditional probability in quantum theory, both at a mathematical and physically meaningful level."  :)

Comment: @mma So what? This does neither raise my appetite to look into that thesis again, nor into OP. It was a hint that got little attention so far.

Comment: It's interesting that despite the difficulties of finding any definite sense of conditional probability, Beltrametti and Cassinelli successfully use it to describe the two-slit experiment, see Enrico G. Beltrametti and Gianni Cassinelli - *The Logic of Quantum Mechanics*, Addison-Wesley, 1981, pp. 283 - 285

Comment: @KurtG. This was just an expression of my surprise.

Comment: @mma Fair enough. The only thing I remember from this thesis is that years ago it helped me to learn some abstract QM stuff. I should probably not have mentioned it since I cannot participate in that discussion without spending lots of time first.